# Google map api in wordpress is showing error

Tags: html, wordpress

This page can't load Google Maps correctly.
Do you own this website?    OK

I get this problem every time. i watched so many youtube video, follow their work, but it didnt work. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is really simple: just replace `YOUR_API_KEY` on the last line of your code with your actual API key!

If you don't have one, you can get it for free on the Google Developers Website.